# How to use recursion or some other technique for following problem

Tags: python, recursion, math, optimization

I have some n-d matrix in which data is filled using indexes. following is a sample code which will give you the idea of what I am trying to implement.

```
# sf = some_function or it can also be considered as array where 
# sf(i) = sf[i]


def sample_function(matrix, matrix2, obj1, obj2):
    for i in range(len(obj1):
        for j in range(len(obj2)):
            for k in range(len(obj3):
                matrix[sf(i)][sf(j)][sf(k)] = matrix2[i][j][k]
```

This is easy to do if I have only 2-3 parameters for function but if parameteres are many how can I do this?
You can assume matrix is already there filled with some value(0).

Comment: what are obj1, obj2?

Comment: you can assume some iterables.

Comment: just to understand, every object will create a new deeper loop? So obj1,obj2, obj3 will produce matrix[obj1[obj2[obj3]]] ?

Comment: yes,  every object will create a new deeper loop.

Comment: Lookup `itertools.product`

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recursive, just makes use of inbuilt itertools, which might still be useful for you... if I understood your question correctly, that is :) Otherwise correct me

```
import numpy  as np
import itertools as it

def other_fun(*args):
    return sum(args)

def sample_fun(mtx, *args):
    for ids in it.product(*[range(len(obj)) for obj in args]):
        mtx[ids] = other_fun(*[obj[idx] for obj,idx in zip(args,ids)])
    return mtx

obj1 = [1,2,3]
obj2 = [4,5,6,7]
obj3 = [8,9]
objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]

mtx = np.zeros([len(obj) for obj in objects])    
mtx = sample_fun(mtx, *objects)
print(mtx)
```

Comment: hey, I just edited question by adding another parameter. please have a look.

Comment: it's still similar-ish:  
```
def sample_fun(mtx1, mtx2, *args):
    for ids in it.product(*[range(len(obj)) for obj in args]):
        mtx1[tuple(sf(idx) for idx in ids)] = mtx2[ids]
```
just now there's no need to pass the "objects" (lists) themselves as arguments - it's sufficient to just pass their lengths